# For $A=\mathbb{Z}_m$, show $A_n=\mathbb{Z}_d$ where $d=gcd(m,n)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, modules, gcd-and-lcm

I am struggling some with proving the following. I am struggling the most with showing $A_n\subseteq\mathbb{Z}_d$.

> Prove that $A_n=\{a|na=0\}$ where $n$ is fixed in $\mathbb{Z}$ is a
>   submodule of $A$. For $A=\mathbb{Z}_m$, show that $A_n=\mathbb{Z}_d$,
>   where $d=(m,m)$.

Below is what I have tried. Also if you could check what I have so far, it would be much appreciated. Thank you!

---

Assume hypothesis. Clearly $A_n\subseteq A$ by definition. We want to show that $A_n$ is a submodule of $A$ by proving (1) $A_n\neq\emptyset$ and (2) $x+zy\in A_n$ for all $z\in\mathbb{Z}$ and for all $x,y\in A_n$.

1. Clearly $0\in A$ because 0 is the additive identity of $\mathbb{Z}$. Notice $n\cdot 0=0$. Therefore $0\in A_n$, which means $A_n\neq\emptyset$. This satisfies the 1st property.
2. Let $z\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $x,y\in A_n$. Then $nx=0$ and $ny=0$. We want to show $x+zy\in A_n$. Consider
   $$
   n(x+zy)=nx+z(ny) = 0 + z\cdot 0 = 0.
   $$
   Therefore $x+zy\in A_n$. This satisfies the 2nd property.

Because the two properties are satisfied, $A_n$ is a submodule of $A$.

Now we want to show that for $A=\mathbb{Z}_m$, we have $A_n=\mathbb{Z}_d$ where $d=\gcd(m,n)$.

$(\subseteq$) Let $x\in A_n$. Then $nx=0$. Then $x\in\mathbb{Z}_n$. Because $A_n$ is a submodule of $A$, we know $x\in A_n\subseteq A=\mathbb{Z}_m$. Therefore $x\in \mathbb{Z}_n\cap \mathbb{Z}_m$. Let $d=\gcd(m,n)$. Notice $\mathbb{Z}_d\subseteq\mathbb{Z}_m\cap\mathbb{Z}_n$.

---

**Question**: Here is where I am getting a little stuck and am not sure how to exactly proceed. I feel like I am missing something obvious to conclude $x\in\mathbb{Z}_d$.

---

($\supseteq$) Let $x\in \mathbb{Z}_d$. Notice $x\in[x]=\{x+zd|z\in\mathbb{Z}\}\in\mathbb{Z}_d$. By a theorem, we know $d=ms+nt$ such that $s,t\in \mathbb{Z}$. Then 
\begin{eqnarray}
x+zd &=& x+z(ms+nt)\\
&=& x+ztn+zsm
\end{eqnarray}
This means $$x\in\{x+zd|z\in\mathbb{Z}\}=\{(x+ztn)+(zs)m|z,t,s\in\mathbb{Z}\}\in\mathbb{Z}_m=A$$
and 
$$x\in\{x+zd|z\in\mathbb{Z}\}=\{(x+zsm)+(zt)n|z,t,s\in\mathbb{Z}\}\in\mathbb{Z}_n.$$ 
Because $x\in\mathbb{Z}_n$, we know $nx=0$. Then because $x\in A$ and $nx=0$, we have $x\in A_n$ by definition.

Therefore $A_n\supseteq \mathbb{Z}_d$.

Hence for $A=\mathbb{Z}_m$, we have $A_n=\mathbb{Z}_d$ where $d=\gcd(m,n)$.

Comment: Minor quibble: "By definition, we know $d=ms+nt$"—this is not the definition of the greatest common divisor, but rather a theorem about it (Bézout's theorem).

Comment: @Martin Thank you for pointing that out. I was going from memory and accidentally made that mistake. I will correct.

Comment: Are you sure about the notation? Take $A = \mathbb{Z}_4$ and $n=2$. Then $A_2 = {0,2}$, which is only isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and not equal.

Comment: The notation I am given is equal. I am positive about that...But I think this might be an error in my text. I need to verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\,\ na\!=\!0$ in $\,\Bbb Z_m\!\!\iff\! m\mid na\!\iff\! m\mid na,ma\!$ $\iff\! m\mid (na,ma)\! =\! \underbrace{(n,m)}_{d}a\!\iff\! m/d \mid a$

$\,\Bbb Z_m\,$ contains $d\,$ multiples of $\,c = m/d,\,$ viz. $\, 0,\, c,\, 2c,\,\ldots, (d\!-\!1)c,\,$ and it is easy to check that they form a subgroup *isomorphic* to $\,\Bbb Z_d.\,$

Comment: Thank you for pointing these facts out to me. It helped me get to the final solution I believe. I was struggling to make the connections above. Does the fact that there are $d$ multiples of $\frac{m}{n}$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ imply that $x\in\mathbb{Z}_d$?

Comment: @jm It seems you misunderstand the notion of isomorphic groups. They need not be based upon the same sets. Rather, there is a bijection between their underlying sets that preserves the group operation. Here the bijection maps $\,k\in \Bbb Z_d$ to $\,kc\in Z_m.\ \ $

Comment: So essentially $\mathbb{Z}_d\cong \mathbb{Z}_m=A$, right? I was trying to show that $A_n=\mathbb{Z}_d$ though.

Comment: @jm No $\ A_n \cong c\,\Bbb Z_m \cong \Bbb Z_d\ \ $