# Does $nx=0$ imply $x\in \mathbb{Z}_n$?

Tags: proof-verification, modular-arithmetic

For some reason, I am having trouble convince myself that $nx=0$ implies $x\in\mathbb{Z}_n$. 
I know if $x\in\mathbb{Z}_n$ that $nx=0$ is true. But does the converse hold?  Here is what I am thinking...

---

I know if $x\sim 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ iff $n|(x-0)$. If $n|(x-0)$, then $n|x$. This means $x=nb$ where $b\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then
\begin{eqnarray}
x&=&nb\\
x^2&=&nxb\\
x^2&=&0\cdot b\\
x^2&=0
\end{eqnarray}
Because $x^2=0$, we know $x=0$. Hence $x\in\mathbb{Z}_n$. Right? I feel like this argument is correct. I am just looking for confirmation.

Comment: Here is a counter example. Take $n=0$ and $x=i$. Then $nx=0$, but $i$ is not in $\mathbb{Z}/n=\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: For example, $\;6\cdot 2=12=0\pmod 6\;$ , yet $\;2\notin\Bbb Z_6\;$ ...did you mean this?

Comment: You should specify what $n$ and what $x$ is in the premise.

Comment: What is $x$ and what does it mean for $x$ to be in $\,\Bbb Z_n?\,$ It seems that you are confusing integers and elements of $\,\Bbb Z_n\,$ (among other things). Please review your definitions.

Comment: You can't define $nx$ until you know what $x$ is. But in $\mathbb Z_6$, $3\cdot 4 = 0$ but $4\not\in\mathbb Z_3$.

Comment: @ryanblack Sure. The term $n$ is fixed in $\mathbb{Z}$ and $x\in A_n=\{a|na=0\}$ where $A$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$ module.

Comment: If $A$ is a $\mathbb Z-$module (aka, an abelian group) then you can just take $n=2$ and $A=\mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_2$. Then $2x=0$ for all $x\in A$, but it doesn't make sense to say such an $x$ is in $\mathbb Z_2$.

Comment: Also, if $A=\mathbb Z_3$ then $9x=0$ for all $x\in A$, but it doesn't make sense to say that $\mathbb Z_3\subseteq \mathbb Z_9$.

Comment: @jm.byrnes Did you intend to ask if $\,A_n\,$ is isomorphic to $\,\Bbb Z_n?\ \ $  The question omits much essential  context.

Comment: What do you mean by $x\sim 0$? In a group, either $x=0$ or not. There is no $\sim$. You seem to be confusing the elements of a group $\mathbb Z_m$ with elements of $\mathbb Z$. The $2$ that is in $\mathbb Z$ is a different animal from the $2$ that is in $\mathbb Z_m$. It doesn't make sense to talk about them as the same entity. We often sloppily write them as the same, but ideally the $2\in\mathbb Z_m$ is written as something like $2+m\mathbb Z$ or $[2]_{m}$ or something similar.

Comment: By the way, $x^2$ doesn't make sense in a $\mathbb Z$-module. It is, again, meaningless.

Comment: Basically, you need to go back to the definitions, and figure out what you mean. Fix your question (people shouldn't need to read comments to find out you mean that $x$ is an element of a $\mathbb Z$-module.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Examining his [prior question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2166506/242) reveals some context.